# Can't get the func in `web3.eth.getAccounts` to run

Tags: metamask, javascript

I'm trying to perform a simple balance check, but the code inside `web3.eth.getAccounts` doesn't run.

I'm trying to get web3 from the instance injected by Metamask.

```
myWeb3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) {
  console.log("why doesn't this run? ");
  myWeb3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0], function(err, balance) {
    render("Your balance is " + window.web3.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
  });
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/q3m178xnl9
src/index.js:26

I'm not really a developer, so it's possible this is something silly on my end.

Thanks a lot ❤️

Answer (score 0):

You should try starting with more simple, easy to read code. Especially when trying to get others to help you debug, you should be providing to us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Here is a better starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/87jhmodc/8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
          window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
          console.log('No Web3 Detected... get Metamask');
        }
      })

      function getBalance() {
        var wei, balance
        try {
          web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) {
            web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0], function(error, wei) {
              if (!error) {
                var balance = web3.fromWei(wei, 'ether');
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = balance + " ETH";
              }
            })
          });
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = err;
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button type="button" onClick="getBalance();">Get Balance</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Take a look here too: [Ethereum and Web3.js “Hello World”: Get the ETH Balance of an Ethereum Address](http://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/ethereum-web3-js-hello-world-get-eth-balance-ethereum-address/)